# Automatically sink() when exiting function when there is a error

Tags: r, error-handling, sink

I want to write a error log for one of my functions (see below). However, when the function fails, the sink won't get closed properly. Is there a way to always close the sinks() upon exiting the function?

```
some_function <- function(){


 con <- file("test.log")
 sink(con, append=TRUE,type="output",split=TRUE)
 sink(con, append=TRUE,type="message")

 >> do some stuff that may fail. 

 sink() 
 sink(type = "message")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `try`.

```
try(lm(1), outFile="error.txt")  ## failing stuff
```

File contains:

```
Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula
```